# Passing form variables to curl request

Tags: php, curl, pushbullet

Alright, so I'm trying to create a simple HTML page with a form to submit a pushbullet request using cURL.

So far, my HTML looks like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Omran's Push Application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" onSubmit="window.location='index.htm" action="post.php">
<p>
<label for="login">From:</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="login">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="message">Message:</label>
  <input type="text" name="body" id="password">
</p>
<p class="login-submit">
  <button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following is the PHP/cURL side of things.

```
<?php
//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['title'] = $_POST['title'];
$post_data['body'] = $_POST['body'];
//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init('https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes');
//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Access-Token: TOKEN_HERE']);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);
?>
```

It's not giving though. It just gives a blank page at post.php

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting post data on post.php page ?

Comment: Where do you expect to receive anything? Try returning the result somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `var_dump($result);` and see what comes back. I don't think you're actually outputting anything hence the blank page

Comment: Alright, turns out I had a bad token there which was causing a failed request on the server side. I can receive the push now, only issue, it's empty.
My guess is something wrong with the variables being passed from the form.

Comment: Maybe, ensure your form passes all required variables to post.php. You can  check that by var_dump($_POST); at the beginning of the post.php script